# Want to move from navigation drawer activity to another screen using fragments to show drawer across all screens

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying for last two days to add fragment next to my drawer activity to get navigation drawer visible across the whole application. I have tried several ways from stackoverflow and many others but still no success. and after that i have to move to 2nd fragment from 1st fragment and so on till the need for navigation drawer. 
I want to replace entire view except drawer when i move from from my activity to any fragment. Each fragment have its own layout.xml like an activity(Linear/Relative layouts as parent in them).

Drawer avtivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Button btnfragOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfrag_one);
    btnfragOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragOne fragment = new FragOne();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frag2, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    });

}
```

1st Fragment class:

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_one, container, false);
}
```

//   2nd Fragment class:

```
public class FragTwo extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_two, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply for this task you have to override `onNavigationItemSelected` method in your `Activity`, which return id of selected fragment on `NavigationDrawer`.

Try this,

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //calling the method displayselectedscreen and passing the id of selected menu

    displaySelectedFragment(item.getItemId());

    return true;
}
```

Now `displaySelectedFragment`,

```
private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {

        case R.id.your_fragment_one_id:
            fragment = new FragOne();
            break;

        case R.id.your_fragment_two_id:
            fragment = new FragTwo();
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_layout_id_which_is_to_be_replace, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_drawer_layout_id);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

**Edit --** If you want navigate from `FragOne` to `FragTwo`. Try this,

Create a method in your `Activity`,

```
public void showFragTwo(){

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragTwo frag = new FragTwo();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.your_layout_id_which_is_to_be_replace, frag);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Then in your `FragOne` when you want to start `FragTwo`, call `startFragTwo` method from `Activity` as,

```
((YourActivity)  getActivity()).showFragTwo();
```

Comment: No, i don't want to move using the drawer/navigation item click, i want to move to next screen by clicking main_content_view item/button click. 
Using navigation items click, i already have a solution.

Comment: Check answer now @UmerFarooq